# how to match equal values in mongodb

Tags: sql, mongodb

I am trying too Find the information of products (khr_asin) that were bought together with at least one other
Product (khr_related.also_bought) which is also in the collection?

Below is my query so far but i am getting result 'false' on my $eq statement. Would anyone be able to help?

Here is my statement so far.

```
db._products.aggregate([ 
{$group: {_id: {asin: '$khr_asin', categories: '$khr_categories', 
 also_bought: '$khr_related.also_bought', description: '$khr_description', 
title: '$khr_title', price: '$khr_price', 
matching: {$eq:[ "$khr_asin", "$khr_related.also_bought" ]} }}}, { $sort: { 
matching: -1 }}  ]);
```

Schema:

asin - ID of the product

related - related products (also bought)

Comment: There seems to be a typo in your query for keys "desccription" and "catergories". Did you look into it ? If its not a typo, then could you please share your schema !

Comment: Sure i have made the changes thanks @CodeReactor